Extending C# syntax highlighting
I am trying to create my own color scheme in the latest version of gVim and I have encountered a problem.
When I try to add a new group for syntax highlighting, for example I want the library connections to be highlighted in a certain color, i.e. the text after using.
I created a file ~/.vim/after/syntax/cs.vim and used the regular expression:
syntax match CSLibrary /\<using\ \zs[A-Za-z0-9_\.]\+/

In my color scheme file, I gave this group a color:
hi CSLibrary guifg=#48b59f guibg=NONE gui=NONE cterm=NONE

When using the command :syn list CSLibrary it is output that the highlighting group exists and even has the correct formatting.
When I execute the command:
match CSLibrary /\<using\ \zs[A-Za-z0-9_\.]\+/

in the current session without using syntax, the highlighting turns on.
How can I correctly create a highlighting group so that it highlights the text I need, please explain
UPDATE:
Added a group redefinition where using was previously specified. Now I just remove it from the keywords.
Added another regular expression for using
Now if you comment out one of the syn matches, the highlighting will work for the one that is not commented out. But if you uncomment both expressions, then only one will always work, and that is using
syntax clear csUnspecifiedStatement

syn keyword csUnspecifiedStatement as in is nameof out params ref 
sizeof stackalloc

syn match CSLibrary /\<using\ \zs[A-Za-z0-9_\.]\+/

syn match myUsingKeyword /\<using\>/


FWIW, ctermfg, ctermbg, and cterm do nothing in GVim.

Added the wrong line, corrected it

Found a solution, in order for the required highlighting to work from the CSLibrary regular expression, you need to remove the use of the word using, most likely because a rule was already used for this keyword, then my regular expression did not find using, because of this the required highlighting did not work
syn match CSLibrary /\ \zs[A-Za-z0-9_\.]\+\ze;/


FWIW, \zs and \ze probably don't do what you want in syntax: they still consume the characters before/after, so future syntax rules can't see them. The Perl-style operators with @ in them don't have that problem AFAIK
